# Changing the TextView text in Listview is not getting reflected

Tags: android, listview

shelf_repots_item_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


 <TextView`enter code here`
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:background="@drawable/back"
       android:textColor="@color/color_black"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:padding="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There are 10 TextView elements added setting with text 
"Setting text View 1", "Setting text View 2" ... "Setting text View 10" properly
You can see adapter getView() below

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   ...

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shelf_repots_item_row, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            title.setBackground(null);
            title.setText("Seting text view :"+position);
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

on item Click of the 4th element I am reading her reading str2 = (String) textView.getText(); and getting the proper string which it got set in getView.
str2 is now "Setting text View 4"

now I am changing textView string with 
textView.setText("changing Text View");

again reading String like str = (String) textView.getText();
str is now "Changing Text View"

But in screen that is not getting reflected.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)parent.getAdapter().getView(position, view, parent);

        TextView textView = (TextView)v.getChildAt(0);
        String str2 = (String) textView.getText();

        textView.setText("Changing Text View");
        textView.setTextColor(R.drawable.back);
        String str = (String) textView.getText();
        ((MyAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Can any body help me and show where I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried below code in getView()
if(convertView != null)
  return convertView;

but it has side effect.
if I set same text to TextView (e.g, "Setting text View" to all)
problem here is, click on one item, i will change the all the other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work like this, Here is why.

as you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` if recalls the `getView` method of list.

Here what you are doing is changing the text

```
    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)parent.getAdapter().getView(position, view, parent);
    TextView textView = (TextView)v.getChildAt(0);
    String str2 = (String) textView.getText();
    textView.setText("Changing Text View");
```

But when you are calling `((MyAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`

the `getView` is getting called again and setting back the text of your text view to `"Seting text view :"+position` because of `title.setText("Seting text view :"+position);`

Hop this clear things up for you.

Mark as right if this helps you.:)

Comment: i cemented this
((MyAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

and tried this, still the same effect textView.invalidate();

Comment: your approach is not right.. pass a string arraylist to the adapter as a parameter in constructor from the activity and create your adapter around this. display string in textview from this arraylist

On onclick event change the text in this arraylist at the perticular position and notify dataset change.

Comment: thanks Nitesh, you are right, it works.
one more question here, what if I want to change the background color for perticulat TextView,

if same text is present in multiple text view, all the textview items background color is getting changed.

Comment: Create a method selectedPosition(int selectedPosition){mSelectedPosition = selectedPosition; notifyDataSetChanged();}
in your adapter. call it from activity wth the position for which you want to highlight the backgroung and place an if( position = mposition){ change color }else{rivert color} in your getview() of adapter

Comment: Hey assuming you are new here, You can accept the answers that properly fits for your questions. If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here:stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . But only if your question really has been answered.

Comment: I have multiple horizontal listviews in a scroll view, how to deselect item from one listview when an item is clicked on another listview?

Comment: please ask a new question and show some code what you have tried.